# BIRT: how to create multiple line charts dynamically in BIRT report

Tags: birt

I have on BIRT report where I need to show testcase id , name in two columns (which I did with dataset), now I need to create line chart for each testcase dynamically. Where as my testcase number is not fixed. So i want to make a script which will create multiple line charts according to date of execution for each test case. first question is it a feasible one? If yes then how to do it?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question and provide some details more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are wishing to add testcases as new 
"series" in chart?

You can add new series inside script, but I'm not sure which phase (action) will be best for it, you'll need to experiment. BUT, this script will be part of your chart, so you won't be able to just access data from the table easily. So to make it possible you will need to make it accessible as a global variable BEFORE chart will start rendering.
Sorry I cannot give you sample solution, but I do not have IDE on this computer, so I cannot check what actions, and what input params we have possible to choose from.

Comment: thanks for  answering szefuf, actually i found the solution.

Comment: @Neha Can you please share how did you solve this. I also want to create multiple line charts in single report.